OrbitControls in ThreeJS not working with import map
I'm trying to get a simple ThreeJs with OrbitControls for pan and zoom. I was able to get a working example with an older version (128), but I'm having trouble with the newer r168.
In the example, I'm trying to write the js code directly into an html page, and importing the threejs dependencies using cdn, instead of a local source.
<body>
    <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.168.0/build/three.module.js",
                "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.168.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="module">
        import * as THREE from 'three';
        import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

        // Scene setup
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        
        // Renderer setup
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000); // Set background color to black
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // Create a cube
        const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
        const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(cube);

        // Position the camera
        camera.position.z = 5;

        // OrbitControls setup
        const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        controls.enableDamping = true; // Enable smooth damping
        controls.dampingFactor = 0.25; // Adjust the damping factor for smoothness
        controls.enableZoom = true;    // Enable zoom
        controls.enablePan = true;     // Enable panning

        // Animation loop
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            controls.update(); // Required if damping is enabled
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        animate();

        // Adjust canvas on window resize
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        });
    </script>
</body>

The code seems to get an error right at the start, in the import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';.
Any help on what might be going on and how to fix this?

To avoid the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
Maybe try this:
<body>
  <script type="importmap">
      {
          "imports": {
              "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.168.0/build/three.module.js",
              "OrbitControls": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.168.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"
          }
      }
  </script>
  <script type="module">
      import * as THREE from 'three';
      import { OrbitControls } from 'OrbitControls';

      // Scene setup
      const scene = new THREE.Scene();
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
      
      // Renderer setup
      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      renderer.setClearColor(0x000000); // Set background color to black
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      // Create a cube
      const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
      const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      scene.add(cube);

      // Position the camera
      camera.position.z = 5;

      // OrbitControls setup
      const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
      controls.enableDamping = true; // Enable smooth damping
      controls.dampingFactor = 0.25; // Adjust the damping factor for smoothness
      controls.enableZoom = true;    // Enable zoom
      controls.enablePan = true;     // Enable panning

      // Animation loop
      function animate() {
          requestAnimationFrame(animate);
          controls.update(); // Required if damping is enabled
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }
      animate();

      // Adjust canvas on window resize
      window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
          camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
          camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
          renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      });
  </script>
</body>

